# How to return validation error messages with Springboot WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

How do I return the custom validation errors for Springboot 3.0 with WebFlux?

I have wired up the following controller

```java
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
//...

@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/organizations")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrganizationController {

    private final OrganizationService organizationService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Organization>> create(@Valid @RequestBody final OrganizationDto organizationDto) {

        return organizationService.create(organizationDto).map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
}
```

The `OrganizationDto` has been setup as:

```java
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
//...

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public final class OrganizationDto {

    @NotNull    
    private String name;

    //...
}
```

And finally I have what I thought was a correct `ValidationHandler/ErrorController`

```java
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ErrorController {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

        final BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
        final List<FieldError> fieldErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
        final Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        fieldErrors.forEach(error -> errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
        
        return errors;
    }

}
```

However if I send a payload to the endpoint in the controller of

```json
{
  "name": null
}
```

I get back

```json
{
    "timestamp": 1677430410704,
    "path": "/organizations/create",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "requestId": "2050221b-2"
}
```

Which is almost what I want, but I'm trying to get the reason why it failed validation into the response but not having any luck

I've put breakpoints on the `handleValidationExceptions` but looks like I'm never getting into it, and I'm also not seeing anything in the server side logs which points to whats going on.

I do have `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation` on my classpath, and I'm using the latest Springboot 3.0.3

Have I missed a step or annotation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by deleting the `ErrorController` and going back to what I had previously tried which was writing a custom implementation of `WebExceptionHandler`

The important thing to note here is that you must set the `@Order` value otherwise this implementation is skipped over and never called (Which is what lead me to ignore this solution originally).

My version of the `WebExceptionHandler`

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebExchangeBindException;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebExceptionHandler;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ValidationHandler implements WebExceptionHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Mono<Void> handle(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final Throwable throwable) {

        if (throwable instanceof WebExchangeBindException validationEx) {
            final Map<String, String> errors = getValidationErrors(validationEx);

            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            return writeResponse(exchange, objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(errors));
        } else {
            return Mono.error(throwable);
        }
    }

    private Map<String, String> getValidationErrors(final WebExchangeBindException validationEx) {

        return validationEx.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(FieldError::getField,
                error -> Optional.ofNullable(error.getDefaultMessage()).orElse("")));
    }

    private Mono<Void> writeResponse(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final byte[] responseBytes) {

        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(responseBytes)));
    }

}
```

This will correctly return the response of:

```json
{
    "name": "must not be null"
}
```

When passing in the request used in my question.

**Note**: If anyone uses this, be careful with the `@SneakyThrows`

Answer (score 0):

I feel you were so close. Would this not help.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(WebExchangeBindException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleValidationExceptions(final WebExchangeBindException ex) {

        final BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
        final List<FieldError> fieldErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
        final Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        fieldErrors.forEach(error -> errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Error message

```
{
    "name": "Should have at least 4 characters"
}
```